# Keep getting this message: [js] SyntaxError: missing ; before statement @(shell):1:8

Tags: javascript, mongodb, api, adobe-brackets

I've been trying to create an API with Mongo.  All my files are in Brackets. When I go to see if Mongo is running on my local server in my Windows Command Prompt, I keep getting this message:   [js] SyntaxError: missing ; before statement @(shell):1:8.

I believe that is referring to line 1 of my server.js file.
This is what I have:

```
var express = require('express');
```

But there doesn't look like there is anything wrong with the synatax.

Any help be really appreciated.

Comment: What command are you executing, and perhaps show some of your code.

Comment: The error is about @(shell):1:8, so let's not guess: what are you _actually_ doing when you get that error? (e.g. show the CLI command that results in that error. And please put that in your question, don't post it as comment)

Comment: CLI command is node server.js in windows